# Is "Barbarians" a good/suitable translation in Romans 1:14?

Tags: romans

King James Bible Romans 1:14

> I am debtor both to the Greeks, and to the **Barbarians**; both to the wise, and to the unwise.

In https://biblehub.com/romans/1-14.htm, 19 out of 27 versions translate Βαρβάροις as *Barbarians*. It sounds derogatory to me. Is there better translation that would satisfy most? Should I modify my understanding of the word *Barbarians*.

Comment: It is perhaps worth pointing out that 'Barbarian' is simply a transliteration of the Greek βάρβαρος, _barbaros_ [Strong 915](https://biblehub.com/greek/915.htm) and the English word has taken on a meaning which is probably derived from the usage in the Authorised Version. (+1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Greek of Rom 1:14 is:

> Ἕλλησίν τε καὶ Βαρβάροις, σοφοῖς τε καὶ ἀνοήτοις ὀφειλέτης εἰμί·

I would translate this rather literally as:

> Both to Greeks and to Barbarians; to wise and to foolish, I am a debtor.

Concerning the operative word here: Βαρβάροις = barbarians (literally) is a pejorative term for non-Greeks.  According to Thayer:

> properly, one whose speech is rude, rough, harsh, as if repeating the
> syllables βαρβαρ (cf. Strabo 14, 2, 28, p. 662; ὠνοματοπεποίηται ἡ
> λέξις, Etym. Magn. (188, 11 (but Gaisf. reads βραγχός for βάρβαρος);
> cf. Curtius, § 394; Vanicek, p. 561)); hence, ... The Greeks used
> βάρβαρος of any foreigner ignorant of the Greek language and the Greek
> culture, whether mental or moral ...

Hence the various Bible versions are divided between "barbarians" and "non-Greeks", except YLT which has "foreigners" (rather interpretive for Young!)

Paul here uses a very common literary device called a hendiadys, which employs two opposites to mean "everything" in some sense.  Such a very common in most languages; for example, in English we have: Day and night = continually, all the time; Searched high and low = searched everywhere; Time and again = repeatedly; Neither one nor the other = nothing; Turn neither to the right nor the left = do not deviate from the current path; For better or worse = under all circumstances, etc, etc.

In Rom 1:14 Paul uses a hendiadys twice:

- Greeks and non-Greeks (ie everyone)
- Wise and foolish (ie, everyone)

Thus, Paul affirms that he is a debtor to everyone, all people, twice!

Comment: (+1) So you would not say that the term 'Barbarian' is pejorative ?

Comment: NigelJ - That is the clear origin of the term as used by "upper-crust" Greeks.  However, it is not clear if Paul intends this overtone of meaning here.  In any case, the intent is "non-Greeks" to create the hendiadys.  Further, "foolish" here also has similar pejorative overtones.

Comment: There was a non-pejorative word for this in 1st century Ancient Greek: ξένος: stranger, foreigner,